# SystemVerilog 'if' statement inside always_comb 'not purely combinational logic' error

Tags: if-statement, system-verilog

I'm confused! And a bit frustrated. I've spent quite a lot of time working on some SystemVerilog in Modelsim. I got it to a certain stage where I could test it on my hardware however compiling in Quartus was unsuccessful. I did understand this may happen but in this case my errors don't seem to make sense.

The code below is inside an always_comb block. When I compile I get the following error:

```
Error (10166): SystemVerilog RTL Coding error at fifo_interface.sv(80): always_comb construct does not infer purely combinational logic.
```

I really don't understand this. This is the code, it's just a mux.

```
always_comb
    if(fifo_select == 0)
    begin
        fifo0_data_in = data_in;
        fifo0_in_clk = in_clk;
        fifo0_in_dn = in_dn;
        in_rdy = fifo0_in_rdy;

        fifo1_in_clk = 0;   //Prevent 'in_clk' entering fifo1
    end

    else
    begin
        if(fifo_select == 1)
        begin
            fifo1_data_in = data_in;
            fifo1_in_dn = in_dn;
            fifo1_in_clk = in_clk;
            in_rdy = fifo1_in_rdy;

            fifo0_in_clk = 0;   //Prevent 'in_clk' entering fifo0
        end 
    end
end
```

When I change the block to type 'always' Modelsim will act strangely. It will break in the code or will crash altogether with the exit code 211. Changing the type back to 'always_comb' does not fix the issue and so I have to restart modelsim to successfully simulate the HDL.

I'm interested to know what the source of the error is?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not assigning all outputs in all branches of the mux. For example, `fifo0_data_in` gets assigned if `fifo_select == 0`. But if `fifo_select == 1` then it gets no value. This implies that `fifo0_data_in` needs to remember what its value was if `fifo_select` changes. Therefore, synthesis will then infer a latch for this output.

Here is what I think you want:

```
always_comb
    if(fifo_select == 0)
    begin
        fifo0_data_in = data_in;
        fifo1_data_in = '0;
        fifo0_in_clk = in_clk;
        fifo1_in_clk = '0;
        fifo0_in_dn = in_dn;
        fifo1_in_dn = '0;
        in_rdy = fifo0_in_rdy;
    end

    else
    begin
        fifo1_data_in = data_in;
        fifo0_data_in = '0;
        fifo1_in_clk = in_clk;
        fifo0_in_clk = '0;
        fifo1_in_dn = in_dn;
        fifo0_in_dn = '0;
        in_rdy = fifo1_in_rdy;
    end
end
```

And, since you appear to be gating the clock to the unused FIFO you could simplify further as shown below:

```
assign fifo0_data_in = data_in;
assign fifo1_data_in = data_in;
assign fifo0_in_dn = in_dn;
assign fifo1_in_dn = in_dn;

always_comb
    if(fifo_select == 0)
    begin
        fifo0_in_clk = in_clk;
        fifo1_in_clk = '0;
        in_rdy = fifo0_in_rdy;
    end

    else
    begin
        fifo0_in_clk = '0;
        fifo1_in_clk = in_clk;
        in_rdy = fifo1_in_rdy;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by nguthrie is right, but you've tripped up over something that's quite important to understand, so I wanted to write a more explicit version.

If we take your code, and simplify it so we're just looking at the assignments to `fifo0_data_in` it'll be easier to talk about.

```
always_comb
begin
    if(fifo_select == 0)
    begin
        fifo0_data_in = data_in;
    end
end
```

So, when `fifo_select` is zero we assign to `fifo0_data_in`, when `fifo_select` isn't zero, we.... errr... do nothing, which means that it needs to keep it's previous value.

What we've described is a "latch", and latches aren't combinatorial (they retain information) so they can't exist in an `always_comb`. They would have to be in an `always_latch` or `always` block.

Unintended latches are a really common bug when using `always` blocks, and in general you never want them. SystemVerilog added `always_comb` so that errors like this told the designer when they'd forgotten to define a value for a signal in a code path (in your case, when `fifo_select` is not zero).

An alternative way to fix this, and a style that's worth being familiar with, is:

```
always_comb
begin
    fifo0_data_in = '0;  // Default value

    if(fifo_select == 0)
    begin
        fifo0_data_in = data_in;
    end
end
```

Here we assign a default value at the start, so regardless if the `if` condition is true or not, something has been assigned to the signal. This style is often easier is there are lots of complex conditions which control the signal.