# SV code: if statement inside always_comb construct does not infer purely combinational logic

Tags: if-statement, system-verilog, quartus, intel-fpga

I cannot figure out the solution to this error, and the only other answer I find online for the same error is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851475/systemverilog-if-statement-inside-always-comb-not-purely-combinational-logic)
I have been stuck on this problem for a while and I feel like I am going in circles. I am not sure what I am skipping. The error points toward the line with the first if statement. What I am trying to achieve in my code is a mode select where mode 1 will display certain information, and mode0 will display different information on an fpga.

```
module modesel(input logic mode, clk, reset, 
                    input logic [6:0] LOAD,
                    input logic [7:0] pc, ac, state, mdr, opcode, value, address,
                    output logic [9:0] LEDR,
                    output logic [7:0] left, middle, right);
    
            up3(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .store_mem(LOAD[0]), .fetch(LOAD[1]), .load_pc(LOAD[3]), .incr_pc(LOAD[2]), .load_iru(LOAD[5]), .load_irl(LOAD[4]), .load_ac(LOAD[6]), 
                      .pc(pc), .ac(ac), .state(state), .mdr(mdr), .opcode(opcode), .value(value), .address(address));
            
               always_comb
            
                if (mode==1) begin//mode1   
                    LEDR[6:0] = LOAD[6:0];
                    LEDR[8:7] = 0;
                    LEDR[9] = 1;
                    left = pc;
                    middle = address;
                    right = mdr;
                    
                end
            
                else if(mode==0) begin//mode0
                    case(state)
                        8'h00: LEDR[7:0] = 8'b0000_0000;
                        8'h01: LEDR[7:0] = 8'b0000_0001;
                        8'h02: LEDR[7:0] = 8'b0000_0010;
                        8'h03: LEDR[7:0] = 8'b0000_0100;
                        8'h04: LEDR[7:0] = 8'b0000_1000;
                        8'h05: LEDR[7:0] = 8'b0001_0000;
                        8'h06: LEDR[7:0] = 8'b0010_0000;
                        8'h07: LEDR[7:0] = 8'b0100_0000;
                        8'h08: LEDR[7:0] = 8'b1000_0010;
                        default: LEDR[7:0] = 8'b0000_0000;
                    endcase
                    LEDR[9:8] = 0;
                    left = opcode;
                    middle = value;
                    right = ac;
                    
                end
                
endmodule
```

I have been able to keep up so far, but whenever I run into a problem like this it is difficult to solve on my own.

I have tried multiple things like adding assign statements outside the always_comb block, and other suggestions from the previous post I linked above, but I am met with more errors. Any help is appreciated.

The up3 module ports are:

```
module up3(input logic clk, reset, 
            output logic store_mem, fetch, load_pc, incr_pc, load_iru, load_irl, load_ac,
            output logic [7:0] pc, ac, state, mdr, opcode, value, address);
```

The exact error message that I receive is:

```
Error (10166): SystemVerilog RTL Coding error at modesel.sv(16): always_comb construct does not infer purely combinational logic.
```

I should add that this module is meant to be called in my testbench for programming my DE0CV FPGA board. The test bench code is:

```
module up3tb(input logic [3:0] KEY,
             output logic [9:0] LEDR,
             output logic [6:0] HEX0, HEX1, HEX2, HEX3, HEX4, HEX5);    

logic [6:0] LOAD;
logic [7:0] PC, AC, STA, MDR, OPC, VAL, ADR, L, M, R;


 modesel test( .mode(KEY[3]), .clk(KEY[0]), .reset(KEY[1]), 
                    .LOAD(LOAD[6:0]),
                    .pc(PC), .ac(AC), .state(STA), .mdr(MDR), .opcode(OPC), .value(VAL), .address(ADR),
                    .LEDR(LEDR[9:0]),
                    .left(L), .middle(M), .right(R));
                    
                
            dual_seg7 L_out(.blank(0), .test(0), .data(L), .segments1(HEX5), .segments2(HEX4));//Left, PC or Opcode
            dual_seg7 M_out(.blank(0), .test(0), .data(M), .segments1(HEX3), .segments2(HEX2));//Middle, Address or Value
            dual_seg7 R_out(.blank(0), .test(0), .data(R), .segments1(HEX1), .segments2(HEX0));//RIght, AC or MDR
            
            
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try to compile your code on another simulator (VCS), I get many messages like:

```
Error-[VIPCBD] Variable input ports cannot be driven
  Variable input ports cannot be driven.
  The input variable port "LOAD" of module "modesel" is connected to output 
  port "store_mem" of module "up3".
  up3 i0( .clk (clk),  .reset (reset),  .store_mem (LOAD[0]),  
  .fetch (LOAD[1]),  .load_pc (LOAD[3]),  .incr_pc (LOAD[2]),  .load_iru 
  (LOAD[5]),  .load_irl (LOA ...
```

You should not drive the inputs of the `modesel` module (within the `modsel` module) with outputs of the `up3` module.  Perhaps `up3` should be outside the `modsel` module.

Also, I had to give `up3` an instance a name: `i0`

```
module up3tb ...
    ...
    modsel test ( ... );
    up3    i0   ( ... );
endmodule
```